# Creating printable content with Php/JavaScript/Html/CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I work for a care centre that would like a feature on their website where friends and family  can choose from a selection of care cards to deliver to someone they know. They will be able to choose a title, an image and type in some text on the card that we assemble and deliver. They need me to make an application for them that assembles the cards in a printer-friendly fashion (placing text and images in the right areas) that they will print and fold before delivery.

Image of what I am trying to create: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddj4L.png

Reading about how to do this I realize that I have two issues:

- Size of card on-screen can't be fixed due to printer DPI
- Should I use html/CSS to make a table with 4 cells to create this card? Php image library? JavaScript?

Any help would great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the best luck, in terms of printing, with PDFs. The document format is nice, too, because it is portable and the user may choose to print somewhere other than where they accessed your site.

The best PDF-generating library I've used for PHP is fPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/

PDFs are great for printing full-page documents. All but the most ancient operating systems provide users the ability to open and print PDFs, and because PDF is a document format the printed output is fairly consistent between systems and printers.

The other route you suggest is certainly possible - you can build it up using HTML and CSS. There are serious drawbacks to this, however. Foremost, each user is going to have varying printer settings in their browser, and the browser is not configured by default to be good to your full-page printing. Most user agents add page numbers, margins, the date & time, the URL.... in short, your print from the browser is going to rely on the **user** tinkering with their browser print settings. There is nothing you can do to influence these settings from your end.

Comment: I just started with html/css and found many issues with it, some of which you mentioned. I shall give PDF's a go! Thanks again.

Comment: fPDF can take some effort to get set up, then you're going to have to do some fishing to get the positioning right. Another thing - if you're going to put images into the PDF, make sure to use PNGs, use a high DPI (300 or so - remember, this is print not web). If you don't, the images will turn out blurry. If you need help with fPDF, ask another question on SO and someone (me, if no one else) will help you.

Comment: fPDF is very confusing indeed. Is my task pretty simple to achieve because I am having a tough time figuring this out

Comment: The hardest part is to get the library set up and generating PDFs with the fonts you want. I would suggest you focus on that first - take one of their samples and tweak it, just to get yourself outputting PDFs using the desired font. Then take the example and throw your image at it (remember high DPI!). Don't worry about what it looks like, just get it to save a PDF with your image in it. THEN go back and start stripping things out of the demo code, but be sure to leave the image and a couple of pieces of text. Verify that you are still outputting PDFs. THEN you can start tweaking positions.

Comment: After you get an example script working, it really will start to come together. But, you'll also have to expect to spend some time tinkering with the positioning, printing tests, over and over. Once you get it locked in, though, this library is reliable and stable.

Comment: Am I able to put images inside a cell? What about rotating images? Rotating text?

Comment: For rotating text, you have to get an addon for fPDF: http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/2/ - I implemented the `Rotate` method into the base class rather than using it as the example there shows.  As far as the images, they are free-floating as far as I know - you have to position them independent of cells. Use multi-cell for most things, BTW, it is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

There are third-party utilities that generate PDFs on the server, based on your HTML. PDFs have solved many print-related issues internally so you don't have to worry about them yourself.